# Terminal will not use updated a.out, how do I fix that?

Tags: c, macos, unix, terminal

I'm compiling a C file on Terminal on my mac, but when I run the a.out file, it will only compile an old version of my file.

For example, let's say my C file is made to print out "Hello, World!", I compile it using gcc and I run the a.out file, the a.out file will print out "Hello, World!".

If I then change the C file to print out "Goodbye", compile it and then run the a.out file, the Terminal will still print out "Hello, World". Does anyone know how to fix this?

All I am typing into the Terminal is

```
gcc main.c
~/a.out
```

Which is all I should be inputting right?

Please let me know if I didn't make anything clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: This might sound silly, but sometimes we forget to save before we compile. Try saving the file again, compiling, and running.

Comment: Can you pls post the output of `pwd` and `ls`

Comment: look at the # of answers saying the same thing!  ok, here's a different fix than what everyone suggested.  try **gcc -o ~/a.out main.c** instead of your gcc line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are typing in

```
~/a.out
```

Which means "run the `a.out` program from the home directory."  I think you want to type

```
./a.out
```

Which means "run the `a.out` program from the current directory."  If you are using `gcc`, the newly-created program will be placed into the current directory (which, unless you're in the home directory, is not the same place), so the new version will run the right program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked! Sorry if this was a silly question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

```
gcc main.c
~/a.out
```

The first line will compile to a.out in your current directory, while the second line executes a.out from your HOME directory. Are you in your home directory?

If not, change the second line to

```
./a.out
```

`.` means current directory. So `./a.out` means execute the `a.out` file in my current directory.

Answer (score 2):

With `~/a.out` you run a binary from *your home directory* (see `echo "$HOME"`), which may be not the one where you're compiling your new `main.c`.

Try this: `./a.out` (run from your current directory).

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
gcc main.c
./a.out
```

Notice the `.` (current directory) rather than `~` (home directory).  The `gcc` command will write a.out to the current directory when it compiles the code, which is not necessarily the home directory.